# SharePoint Search Result after updated Metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, metadata, crawling, managed-property

In SharePoint Online I have a document library with a column "HFMetadataStatus". This column is just a "single line of text" property and has a default value of "unset".
I copied 1000 files in the library and all of them got "HFMetadataStatus = unset" as exspected.

When I used the SharePoint Search with the query "Querytext": "HFMetadataStatus: unset" I got all items of this library as a result.

On the next day I changed the value from "unset" to "Done" on all files.
After one week I searched again for "Querytext": "HFMetadataStatus: unset" and expected to get zero results, because I updated the property.
But unfortunately I still get the exact same result like before my change.
How can this be? Anybody has an idea what might go on here? I added HFMetadataStatus as a managed property of cause, but the index seems not to be updated for any reason.

How can I debug that?

Comment: What's the crawl schedule for the web applications?

Comment: Crawl schedule? Do I even have access to SPO crawl schedule?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the SPO reference. Use Kasper's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a good idea to download the Sharepoint search query tool and have a look at the raw values from the query. If it shows the same result I'll say that is likely that the crawler is not working on your tenant and open a support ticket.
Btw it is a fact that MS has a major issue with the search engine these day and properties are not crawled(SP148979).Perhaps it could be related to that

Comment: Yes, I will open a ticket. Probably the best solution. My index is still wrong...

Answer (score 1):

You could try to reindex on that document library

**Ribbon Library > Library settings > Advanced Settings > Reindex Document Library**

Comment: That will not trigger the search engine to start a crawl, but will mark it as dirty for the next time the crawler is running